# Web scraping classes in Python with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a webscraper that scrapes the past/upcoming matches + results from this site https://bayesbet.everettsprojects.com/.

I already figured how to get the matches but when I try to access the Home/Away Probability, im getting stuck...

Picture of the code where the href link is stored:
[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ashtp.png)

To clarify what I'm trying to achieve, I want to scrape the probability too which I marked in the screenshot below:

Home Team - Away Team - Home Probability (marked in red) - Away Probability (marked in blue) [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b5GI.png)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, re, urllib.parse

url = requests.get("https://bayesbet.everettsprojects.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
matches = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"game_link"})


for match in matches:
    stats = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class_":"outcome-plot"})
    print(stats)
    awayprobability = stats.find("g", class_="away-prob")
    print(awayprobability)
    print(match.text)
```

Problem facing when using Selenium - [Inside Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK34I.png)

Same Class names on website - [Website HTML/CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Jc4.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are there.* What do you find them in your `soup`?

Comment: "Predited Win Probability" this is data which are rendered on the client(using js). You need to use selenium to get them.

Answer (score 0):

Since on this site the data you need is generated on client, you can use Selenium to get it:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# run selenium in headless mode
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"])

service = Service(executable_path='path/to/your/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get('https://bayesbet.everettsprojects.com/')

matches = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="game_link"]')
away_labels = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'text[class="away-label"]')
away_prob = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'text[class="away-prob"]')
home_labels = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'text[class="home-label"]')
home_prob = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'text[class="home-prob"]')

for idx, data in enumerate(zip(away_labels, away_prob, home_labels, home_prob)):
    print(matches[idx].text)
    print(f"Predited Win Probability: {data[0].text} - {data[1].text}")
    print(f"Predited Win Probability: {data[2].text} - {data[3].text}")

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
2022-10-07 - San Jose Sharks @ Nashville Predators
Predited Win Probability: SJS - 25.62%
Predited Win Probability: NSH - 74.38%
2022-10-07 - Buffalo Sabres @ Pittsburgh Penguins
Predited Win Probability: BUF - 25.46%
Predited Win Probability: PIT - 74.54%
2022-10-07 - Toronto Maple Leafs @ Detroit Red Wings
Predited Win Probability: TOR - 67.05%
Predited Win Probability: DET - 32.95%
2022-10-07 - Seattle Kraken @ Edmonton Oilers
Predited Win Probability: SEA - 20.99%
Predited Win Probability: EDM - 79.01%
2022-10-07 - Winnipeg Jets @ Calgary Flames
Predited Win Probability: WPG - 29.09%
Predited Win Probability: CGY - 70.91%
2022-10-07 - Arizona Coyotes @ Vancouver Canucks
Predited Win Probability: ARI - 21.83%
Predited Win Probability: VAN - 78.17%
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your that response! I only face a problem while using selenium as the match score has the same class name and when I try to scrape that it sometimes scrapes the "Actual Score" text instead of the score number. I edited my post and attached the screenshot at the end so you see what I mean.

Comment: My bad.. did use the wrong CSS element, thank you very much tho, got it up and running!